# How to convert hexadecimal string (with float) to binary in C?

Tags: c, string, binary, hex

I already have a program that converts hexadecimal numbers into its binary form, the only problem is that it does not accept hexadecimals with float. Here is the code:

```
    /* HEXADECIMAL TO BINARY */
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define MAX 1000

    int main(){
char hexaDecimal[MAX], *pch;
long int i=0;
clrscr();
printf("Enter any hexadecimal number: ");
scanf("%s",hexaDecimal);
printf("\nEquivalent binary value: ");

while(hexaDecimal[i]){
     switch(hexaDecimal[i]){
         case '0': printf("0000"); break;
         case '1': printf("0001"); break;
         case '2': printf("0010"); break;
         case '3': printf("0011"); break;
         case '4': printf("0100"); break;
         case '5': printf("0101"); break;
         case '6': printf("0110"); break;
         case '7': printf("0111"); break;
         case '8': printf("1000"); break;
         case '9': printf("1001"); break;
         case 'A': printf("1010"); break;
         case 'B': printf("1011"); break;
         case 'C': printf("1100"); break;
         case 'D': printf("1101"); break;
         case 'E': printf("1110"); break;
         case 'F': printf("1111"); break;
         case 'a': printf("1010"); break;
         case 'b': printf("1011"); break;
         case 'c': printf("1100"); break;
         case 'd': printf("1101"); break;
         case 'e': printf("1110"); break;
         case 'f': printf("1111"); break;
     default:  printf("\nInvalid hexadecimal digit %c ",hexaDecimal[i]);
     return 0;
     }
     i++;
}
    getch();
return 0;
}
```

I tried splitting the string using strtok but it doesn't work.. All I need is for this program to also work with hexadecimal fractions. Thanks for the responses in advance!

Comment: What kind of input are you entering? What do you mean by "Hexadecimals with float"?

Comment: shouldnt you have a  case '.'

Comment: Does input include `e` for exponentiation?  How about `-`, `+`, `.`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add to your `switch` block:

```
case '.': printf("."); break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **strtoul** defined in **stdlib.h** you can convert any radix base to decimal from this method including Hexa-decimal.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)